# Count Number of elements in string in pandas cell

Tags: python, pandas

My data look like this

```
>df
    Employee     Entries
0       A     abc,sed,yrs,sef
1       B       wes,det,fyd
```

I want to count how many words are there in each row for column 'entries'. So first row is 4, second one 3.

I tried

```
# Count Comma and add 1
df['Entries_Count'] = df.Entries.str.count(',')+1
```

Which would be okay I some rows were not empty.

So how do i count elements in each cell. Also this is not a list, but a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.str.count` with `regex`

```
  Employee          Entries
0        A  abc,sed,yrs,sef
1        B      wes,det,fyd
2        C          oneword # Added for a demonstration
3        D                  # Added for a demonstration
4        E              NaN # Added for a demonstration

df['Entries'].str.count('\w+')
```

Output:

```
0    4.0
1    3.0
2    1.0
3    0.0
4    NaN
Name: Entries, dtype: float64
```

You can add `sum` to get total count:

```
df['Entries'].str.count('\w+').sum()
```

Output:

```
8
```

Answer (score 1):

Use can use lambda function as well: 
`df['Entries_Count'] = df['Entries'].apply(lambda x: x.count(',')+1)`